# Plotting horizontal lines in gnuplot on an existing graph, using the same coloured lines

Tags: gnuplot

The starting point is that I have a graph with 4 lines on it. They are the results of my simulation, plotted over an x-axis of iteration, at 4 different locations.  I also have experimental values at each of those locations.  I want to plot those 4 experimental values as horizontal lines on the same graph.  I would also like the line colours of the simulation and experiment results at each location to be the same.

With @Tom's help, below, I have got the following script to do this:

```
unset bars
max = 1e6
set xrange[7000:24000]
set yrange[-0.5:1.5]
plot for [i=2:5] 'sim' using 1:(column(i)) ls i, \
for [i=1:4] 'expt' using (1):1:(max) every ::(i-1)::(i-1) with xerror ls i ps 0
```

The problem is that I want the values in `xrange[x_min:x_max]` and `yrange[y_min:y_max]` to be taken from `sim` and `expt` as follows:

```
x_min = min(sim[:1])   # where min(sim[:1]) means "min value in file 'sim' col 1"
x_max = max(sim[:1])
y_min = min(sim[:2],sim[:3],sim[:4],sim[:5],expt[:1])
y_max = max(sim[:2],sim[:3],sim[:4],sim[:5],expt[:1])
```

My OS is Scientific Linux: Release 6.3, Kernel Linux 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64, GNOME 2.28.2

`sim` and `expt` are .txt files

A representative sample of `sim` is:

```
7520    0.282511    0.0756715   -0.222863   -0.0898819
7521    0.315944    0.201687    -0.321723   -0.106345
7522    0.230956    0.102217    -0.34196    -0.061009
7523    1.460043    -0.00118292 -0.045077   0.673926
```

A representative sample of `expt` is:

```
1.112
0.123
-0.45
0.862
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I appreciate that you've already made an effort to reduce the complexity of the problem but there are still a lot of specific details that are potentially clouding the issue. At the moment it is still quite a lot of work for someone to reproduce the problem. Your introductory paragraph and closing remarks aren't really relevant to the question, so maybe you should consider removing them.

Comment: I know that it can be difficult to get started with gnuplot. In your questions there are several unclear parts. After you've written your question you must ask yourself: did I include enough information for other so that the can reproduce my problem? How does your file at `path_to_file` look like? How does the file where `path_to_expt` should come from look like? Which OS do you have? etc. On one question I gave you a link to another question which in my opinion was about the same thing (extract a single value from a data file). I never got any feedback. That's what comments are for.

Comment: I +1'd your comment and I +1'd your answer to the post you pointed me towards.  I was trying to work with the `stats` command and then pursued another path.  I'm sorry, I didn't comment.  I am still trying to figure this out and, when I've done it, I will comment appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is a way to solve your problem:

```
unset bars
max = 1e6
set xrange[0:8]
plot for [i=1:4] 2*i+sin(x) ls i, \
for [i=1:4] 'expt' using (1):1:(max) every ::(i-1)::(i-1) with xerror ls i ps 0
```

Based on some information I found on [Gnuplot tricks](http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~zov1/gnuplot/html/varigrid.html), I have (ab)used error bars to produce horizontal lines based on the points in this data file:

```
2
4
6
8
```

The `(1):1:(max)` specifies that a point should be plotted at the coordinate `(1, y)`, where `y` is read from the data file. The `max` is the value of `xdelta`, which determines the size of the `x` error bar. This is one way of achieving a horizontal line in your plot, as a suitably large value of `max` will result in an error bar across the entire `xrange` of your plot.

Here's what the output looks like:

[image: plot with horizontal lines]

Comment: Thanks for this, @Tom.  I'm starting with your answer as it seems easier to understand.  I have a question about `xrange`.  Can I use arguments in `xrange` that come from `path_to_file`?  In answer to @Christoph's comment, above, `path_to_file` is a plain text document, size: 121 columns, ~16,000 rows.  I want the arguments of `xrange[min:max]` to be `min`=`path_to_file[row=0:col=1]` and `max`=`path_to_file[row=last:col=1]`.  I don't how many rows `path_to_file` will have.  `path_to_expt`is also a plain text file, size: 31 columns, 121 rows.  My operating system is Scientific Linux 6.3 x86_64.

Comment: I ran your script (manually inputting values for `xrange[min:max]` and noticed that the horizontal lines were only plotted if their values were within the `yrange`.  I'm not setting the `yrange`, because previously the default settings have worked, but I think I now need to `set yrange[min:max]`.  My question is similar to the question in my comment, above.  I want `min`=min(path_to_expt[col(28)]) and `max`=max(path_to_expt[col(28)]).  Is it possible to set arguments in `yrange` that come from `path_to_expt`?

Comment: Haven't got time to look at this at the moment but maybe later on. In the meantime, it would be helpful to make some modifications to your question to include all of these details and a small, representative sample of your data if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Have modified question but it is significantly different from original question, because I realise your answer answers my original question.  Would it be better to accept your answer and start a new question?

Comment: Yes, normally it's better to start a new question in this case.

Comment: If you have time, would you mind explaining what `using (1):1:(max)` does in your answer?  I've tried to understand it from the gnuplot Quick Reference card but I can't figure it out.  I know what the middle `1` does and can guess what the `(max)` does but I can't figure out what the `(1)` does.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Considering, that you have a data file with five columns, one with the x-values and four with y-values. Now you have additional file where a number `path_to_expt` comes from. In order to plot the columns and one horizontal line having the y-value `path_to_expt` you can use

```
plot for [i=2:5] path_to_file using 1:(column(i))
```

This plot col 2 against 1, 3 vs 1, 4 vs 1 and 5 vs 1. To get different styles, just use `set linetype` to redefine the automatically assigned line types:

```
set linetype 1 lc rgb 'orange' 
# ... other lt definitions
plot for [i=2:5] path_to_file using 1:(column(i))
```

If you don't want to overwrite exising linetype 1..4, use e.g. 11..14:

```
set linetype 11 lc rgb 'orange'
# ...
plot for [i=2:5] path_to_file using 1:(column(i)) lt (9 + i)
```

Finally, in order to plot a horizontal line, using the same x-values as in the data file, use

```
mynumber = 27
plot path_to_file using 1:(mynumber)
```

If you don't put a number in parentheses, it is interpreted as column number (like the `1` here), whereas put inside parentheses, it is treated as number.

Another option would be to set arrows:

```
set arrow from graph 0, first mynumber to graph 1, first mynumber lt 1
plot for [i=2:5] path_to_file using 1:(column(i))
```

Comment: Thanks, @Christoph.  I went with Tom's answer in the end but I found your answer very useful!